# Internet Banking option for US regions

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

Internet banking option available in US Region, Please suggest the API or Payment gateway link

I have checked Amazon they are using only Credit/Debit card Payment only

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which specific online banking options you're looking for - but a good overall solution for a payment gateway (in US and Europe) is BlueSnap. They have a good API for taking in payments via CC, bank electronic check (ECP), paypal, visa wallets and so on.

The API is this: https://developers.bluesnap.com/

If you plan to take payments via a website, they have a good hosted pages solution, so you could just embed the checkout in your page.

Comment: In India, with out credit/debit card do the payment by online internet banking. If i have account in axis bank i can use my axis customer Id to do the payment. The same thing is possible in USA

Comment: Yes. In the USA, an Electronic check payment (ECP) allows to pay online by supplying the customer bank details without using a Credit Card. BlueSnap allows using ECP and some other alternative payment methods. There are some other payment providers in the US who also offer alternative to credit card payments.